# How can I divide a List object into different sheets when ever it exceeds 65000?

Tags: java

I have a list object that contains 90000 records now i need to cut the list object into diffrent excel reports whenever it exceeds 65000 .then i need to print 1 to 65000 in one excel and remaining all in next sheet. let say i have 150000 records at that i need use 3 excel sheets here is one example list size is 200000 if we devide total list with page limit 200000/60000=geeting nearly 3 excel sheets

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<65000;j++)
  {
      list.add(j);
      //logic to export into excel
  }
}
```

In this situation how can I print the remaining 5000 records? Can anyone please help me how to write a condition for this logic?

Comment: You can write several CSV files relatively easily. Excel will be able to open them.

Comment: thanks for the reply here the question is about how can i devide my list object diffrent pices . i know the logic might eassy but i am not getting. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

Check whether this logic might helps!

```
for(int i=0; i<200000; i++ ){
              if(i%65000==0){
                  // logic export to excel
              }
          }
```

Comment: That will (probably incorrectly) trigger export for the first item in the list. Beware!

Comment: `if (i % 650000 == 0 && i > 0)` condition will work for first item also.

Comment: Depends on logic proceedings, it can be decided whether to export first item!

Comment: Thanks hemanth, now the problem is i am getting an excel report at 65000 iteration,130000 and 1,95000 totally i got 3 excels but i need to print remaining 5000 records into excel!

Comment: You will get four excel according to above logic i.e at 0, 65000, 130000 and 195000 respectively! Post your code to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume that you have `List<Record> records = ....`

then you can do it by:

```
int ctr = 0;
int sheetNo = 1;

for(Record record : records){

   if(ctr <= 65000){
       list.add(record);
   }else{
       //Create new Sheet
       sheetNo++;
       // reset the counter.
       ctr = 0;
   }
ctr++;

}
```